# Hoja de transformación xslt no accede al dato

Tags: xsl

Tengo el siguiente XML que tengo que transformar con una hoja XSLT.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <soap:Body>
       <openAccount xmlns="http://andera.com/NAO/">
            <reqxml>valor</reqxml>
        </openAccount>
    </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

La Hoja de transformación que estoy utilizando es:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:template match="/">
   <soapenv:Envelope 
xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"xmlns:v1="http://www.isban.es/webservices/ANDSOV/Appcuentaandera_e/F_andsov_app
cuentaandera_e/intranet/ACANDSOVAppCuentaAndera/v1">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <v1:openAccount facade="ACANDSOVAppCuentaAndera">
        <reqxml> <xsl:value-of select="//reqxml"/></reqxml>
      </v1:openAccount>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Tras compilarla el resultado es:

Como se puede apreciar en la salida, no está pintando en el tag `<reqxml>` el dato 'valor' que me llega de entrada en el xml.

Si del xml de entrada quito el atributo `xmlns="http://andera.com/NAO/"` del tag `<openAccount>` sí que funciona. Ese atributo me va a llegar siempre, por lo que no puedo quitarlo.

¿Alguna idea de cómo acceder a ese valor teniendo definido ese atributo?

Answer (score 1):

Encontré la solución!

```
<reqxml> <xsl:value-of select="."/></reqxml>
```

Poniendo en el select "." accede a la variable.